# Identify the platform of user who is performing the api call

Tags: php, parsing, user-agent, platform

I have created web services using PHP for mobile applications (Android, iPhone or other).

Now I want to identify the platform of user who is calling my api service using PHP, so how can I do that?

In other words, the api call is being made from two different devices, I want that device's platform name.

Please help.

There is a good php function to parse the user agent, but it does not work when the request is from an Android app or iPhone app. Here is the link: https://github.com/donatj/PhpUserAgent

Comment: You can try looking at the user-agent string in the request headers, but it's not guaranteed to be present, it can be spoofed easily, and even if neither of these things is true, the content won't always give you an accurate indication of the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote said function you linked and the commenter is correct in that if your request is not explicitly sending a user agent header there is nothing for the script to parse and no way to know the platform making the request.